# Getting the € with htmlentities

Tags: php, character-encoding, html-entities

I am really trying to show what htmlentities gives me, but it doesn't give & euro; for the € character.

I am trying

```
echo htmlentities(htmlentities("LISBOA-VIENA DESDE 99€ TAXAS INCLUÍDAS, RESERVE JÁ",ENT_COMPAT,ISO-8859-1),ENT_COMPAT,ISO-8859-1);
    echo '<br>';
    echo htmlentities(htmlentities("LISBOA-VIENA DESDE 99€ TAXAS INCLUÍDAS, RESERVE JÁ",ENT_COMPAT,UTF-8),ENT_COMPAT,UTF-8);
```

and for both I get

LISBOA-VIENA DESDE 99€ TAXAS INCLU& Iacute;DAS, RESERVE J& Aacute;

LISBOA-VIENA DESDE 99€ TAXAS INCLU& Iacute;DAS, RESERVE J& Aacute;

I never get a & euro;

Anyone know how to get this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is discussed [here](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/euro.html); it seems € (`&#8364;`) works often.

Answer (score 8):

What is the original file encoding of the file in which you use these statements?

If you're on Windows chances are high that the file is encoded with [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (CP1252) and not in [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), [ISO-8859-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15) or [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

The `€` sign is `0x80` in Windows-1252, ISO-8859-15 encodes the `€` sign with `0xA4` while ISO-8859-1 doesn't have a `€` sign altogether ([see answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416161/getting-the-with-htmlentities#416196) from Aron Rotteveel).
You must ensure that you pass the correct charset used for the string into [`htmlentities()`](http://de.php.net/htmlentities). Best practice would be to use UTF-8 encoding for all of your files.

If `htmlentities("LISBOA-VIENA DESDE 99€ TAXAS INCLUÍDAS, RESERVE JÁ",ENT_COMPAT,'Windows-1252')` works then you're using the CP1252 charset.

**I also just noticed that you're missing quotes around the charsets in your example above. This could also be the cause of trouble.**

Answer (score 6):

Use `ISO-8859-15` instead of `ISO-8859-1`.

`ISO-8859-15 (ISO Latin 9)` differs from `ISO-8859-1 (ISO Latin 1)` and adds the Euro sign and French and Finnish letters missing in `Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1)`.

```
echo htmlentities('Working htmlentities() now 99€ off!', ENT_COMPAT, 'ISO-8859-15');
```

should return

```
Working htmlentities() now 99&euro; off!
```